# How exactly can I overload the '{' operator?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

To initialize an std::vector, I can directly use the initializer_list, like so:

```
std::vector<int> myVec = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

If i create a custom List Class (which will hold a number of items), for example `class customVector` (for simplicity only with ints, I think I could figure out how to do it with templates myself, if necessary), can I overload the operator '{' in such a way that an instance of `customVector` can be initialized in the same matter? So that I could write

```
customVector myCustomVec = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: `{` is not an operator and therefore cannot be overloaded.  Operators are https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Operators

Comment: You can do what `vector` does and add a constructor that takes an `initializer_list` parameter.

Comment: Well, no, you can't overload the `{` operator, since `{` is not an operator.   Give your class a constructor that accepts an argument of `std::initializer_list<something>` where `something` is a type that makes sense for that class.

Comment: On a side note, read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). (Your problem is one.)

Comment: See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list , especially the example's `S`.

Comment: Btw, `{}` can be used by any constructor, not just one using `std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you ultimately want, but not by overloading any operators – `{` is not an operator.

`vector` does this by having a constructor that takes an `initializer_list` parameter, and you can do the same with your class.

Learning how to do it and implementing it left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, since `{` is not an operator. Up to `C++20`, the following operators were overridable:

```
+    -    *    /    %    ^    &    |    ~    !    =
<    >    +=   -=   *=   /=   %=   ^=   &=   |=   <<
>>   >>=  <<=  ==   !=   <=   >=   &&   ||   ++   --
,    ->*  ->   ()   []
```

`C++20` added the spaceship operator `<=>` but I believe that's it.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have pointed at, `{` is not an operator. However, you can still use the [initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as you like. It's a part of the standard library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct customVector {
    customVector(std::initializer_list<T> list) : size(list.size()) {
        arr = new T[size];
        int count = 0;
        for(auto val: list) arr[count++] = val;
    }
    T* arr;
    std::size_t size;

    ~customVector() {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
        delete [] arr;
    }
};

int main() {
    customVector<int> myCustomVec = {1, 2, 3, 4};
}
```